# javafx.fxml.LoadException: Controller value already specified

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have looked at the posts for this and Im still stuck - any help please?
I am trying to display a line chart in scenebuilder (IntelliJ) - but keep getting different errors about constructors.The last error was 
'JavaFX Error : Controller already specified'but have removed it previously and still get an error.

and have tried different arguments in Main for FXMLLoader with the  loader.setController(...) line, and no luck. I keep reading about sometimes factory controllers are needed if arguments are being passed to the constructor - so think it might be this, but dont know how to write one.Any suggestions please? or good links for me to read up?

My last attempt for FXMLLoaderCode from Main below...

```
   FXMLLoader loader = new  FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/sample/view/graph.fxml"));
    loader.setController(new Controller(sortList));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
```

If anybody has any useful links so I could read up about factory controllers that would be really good. My full code is below.

My programs are
**Main**(Main.java)
entry point for program and uses FXML loader
**Model**(SortList.java)
places numbers in x and y(abscissa ordinate) groups
**Controller**(Controller.java)
add x,y to graph
**View**(graph.fxml)
graph xml displays x-y line chart
**ReadInData**(ReadInData.java)
Reads in and parses numbers

**Errors**

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: Controller value already specified.
/C:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/myjavafx/out/production/myjavafx/sample/view/graph.fxml:18

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:914)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:32)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Model (SortList.java)**

```
public class SortList {

    private final double abscissa;
    private final double ordinate;

    public SortList(double abscissa, double ordinate) {
        this.abscissa = abscissa;
        this.ordinate = ordinate;
    }

    public double getabscissa() {
        return abscissa;
    }

    public double getordinate() {
        return ordinate;
    }


}
```

**View (graph.java)**

fxml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.ScatterChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane"
            maxHeight="-Infinity"
            maxWidth="-Infinity"
            minHeight="-Infinity"
            minWidth="-Infinity"
            prefHeight="400.0"
            prefWidth="600.0"
            xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            fx:controller = "sample.controller.Controller">


    <children>
        <ScatterChart layoutX="76.0" layoutY="33.0" prefHeight="335.0" prefWidth="449.0" title="Test Graph">
            <xAxis>
                <CategoryAxis label="X axis" pickOnBounds="false" side="BOTTOM" />
            </xAxis>
            <yAxis>
                <NumberAxis label="Y axis" side="LEFT" upperBound="1000.0" />
            </yAxis>
        </ScatterChart>
    </children>

</AnchorPane>
```

**Controller (Controller.java)**

```
package sample.controller;

import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import sample.model.SortList;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {
    public LineChart<Double, Double> lineChart;
    private final ArrayList<SortList> sortList;
    public LineChart label1;

    public Controller(ArrayList<SortList> sortList)


    {

        this.sortList = sortList;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        XYChart.Series<Double, Double> graphLine = new XYChart.Series<Double, Double>();

        for (SortList sortlist : sortList) {

            graphLine.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(sortlist.getabscissa(), sortlist.getordinate()));
        }
        lineChart.getData().add(graphLine);
    }
}
```

**Main (Main.java)**

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import sample.IO.ReadInData;
import sample.controller.Controller;
import sample.model.SortList;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Line Chart Sample");
        final ArrayList<SortList> sortList = ReadInData.ReadData("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Java problem\\test.csv");

        try {

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/sample/view/graph.fxml"));
            loader.setController(new Controller(sortList));
            Parent root = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();

            loader.setControllerFactory(new Callback<Class<?>, Object>(){
                @Override
                public Object call(Class<?> param) {
                    return null;
                }

            });



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

```
public class SortList {

    private final double abscissa;
    private final double ordinate;

    public SortList(double abscissa, double ordinate) {
        this.abscissa = abscissa;
        this.ordinate = ordinate;
    }

    public double getabscissa() {
        return abscissa;
    }

    public double getordinate() {
        return ordinate;
    }


}
```

**Input/Output Read in File (ReadInData.java)**

```
package sample.IO;

import sample.model.SortList;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReadInData {

    private static final String COMMA_DELIMITER = ",";

    static public ArrayList<SortList> ReadData(String filename) {

        BufferedReader br = null;

        ArrayList<SortList> inputList = new ArrayList<SortList>();

        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

            String line = "";

            br.readLine();

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] inputData = line.split(COMMA_DELIMITER);

                if (inputData.length > 0) {

                    try {
                        double abscissa = Double.parseDouble(inputData[0]);
                        double ordinate = Double.parseDouble(inputData[1]);

                        SortList row = new SortList(abscissa, ordinate);
                        inputList.add(row);

                    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return inputList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your FXML file with Scene Builder and check this 
[image: Scene Builder]